# What are for-each expressions in Java translated to?

Tags: java, foreach

```
 for ( SomeListElement element : objectWithList.getList() ) { ... }
```

What is the above snippet translated to?

What I am mostly interested in is if the `getList()` method called once, or with each iteration/element?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Comment: This is a shorthand for `Iterator` solution.

Comment: What research did you perform before asking this question? The language specification seems to be an obvious place to look, and it gives the answer very clearly. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: Can't you try yourself by adding a side effect on getList ?

Comment: @JonSkeet I stumbled upon on this, and a side-comment which drawn my attention: `for-each`, in the spec, in the documentations (different JDK docs) or even in many books is referred to as "syntactic sugar / enhanced for loop" for iterating over a *Iterable* collections, which makes clear sense. Even [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) exemplifies Iterable, and the corresponding bytecodes (foreach vs. for) are super similar. I wonder is foreach really using `iterator()` behind the scenes or.. Your link says it's used for arrays as well.. meh.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: For iterables, it uses `iterator()`. For arrays, it doesn't. The JLS is the canonical source for this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Its equivalent to

```
for(Iterator<SomeListElement> i = objectWithList.getList().iterator(); 
                                                              i.hasNext(); ) {
  SomeListElement element = i.next();
  //access element here
}
```

Answer (score 26):

It gets translated to below code snippet, and `objectWithList.getList()` is called only once.

```
for (Iterator i = objectWithList.getList().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    SomeListElement e = (SomeListElement) i.next();
}
```