# What deos following loop do?

Tags: java

I saw the following code on a website but do not know what does this do, when I use it it shows an error.

```
 for(String next: var)
```

Comment: Only that line of code? What about the rest. You says it "shows an error": what is the error?

Comment: I _knew_ the answer... But your question is super vague: "when I use it it shows an error" you don't even say how you use it

Comment: is this really worth being a question on SO?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433282/java-for-each-loop

Answer (score 3):

Its java `for each loop`. where var is a reference which implements `iterable`

[**An enhanced for loop for the Java™ Programming Language**](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/enhanced-for.html)

see:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

[And see how its translates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274852/what-are-for-each-expressions-in-java-translated-to/16274893#16274893)

Comment: It doesn't have to be a list. It can be any Collection or Array.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj it doesn't even have to be a Collection or an array. The only requirement is that the reference implements `Iterable` of some type. That it works on arrays as well is a bonus, as arrays do not implement it.

Comment: Thankyou all.My confusion.Edited.

Answer (score 2):

its called **for each** loop in Java

for it to work, `var` should be of type `String[]` OR `Collection<String>` which is essentially `Iterable<String>`

its equivalent of

```
for(int i=0; i < var.length; i++) {
   String next = var[i];
}
```

in case of `var` is `String[]`

and

```
for (Iterator<String> itr = var.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
{
   String next = itr.next();

}
```

in case where `var` is `Collection<String>`

Answer (score 2):

It's like writing:

```
for (Iterator<String> itr = var.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
{
   String str = itr.next();
   ...
}
```

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for details.

Comment: Naah. You got the variable names mixed up.

Comment: +1 For being the first answer to actually explain how it works.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's _like_ writing this, since your answer allows to use the `remove()` method of the iterator object. You can't do such things with a for-each loop.

Comment: It allows. But it doesn't use `remove()`. Imagine it as a black box :) This is what I give you.

Answer (score 1):

it will iterate loop till your next variable has values.
you can access that value using next variable

Answer (score 0):

a very interesting question for beginners, this is a **foreach** loop similar to for loop, it will assign each value of var which is any array of type String to next.

for more information refer this
[for each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 0):

`var` must be `List of String` Objects ,

`for(Object s:List){}`  is a `For each loop` or enhanced for each loop.

It is easy to iterate like this , rather than using

```
List<String> var=new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0;i<var.length();i++)

    {
        String s=var.get(i);   //var is a list of String
        System.out.println(s);

    }
```

For each is used this way

```
for(String s:var)
{
   System.out.println(s);   //much easy
}
```

So to ease up Java allows for each loop to iterate through List through for each.

Comment: ... `var` must implement `Iterable<String>` or a string array.

Comment: @aioobe ...correct... it is being worked as a closure in lambda project by oracle...http://www.javac.info/closures-v05.html