# ArrayList loop performance in ART (Android Runtime Environment)

Tags: java, android, performance, arraylist

I have read the performance tips here:
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops
and at the time it looks like

```
for(i=0; i <= objectArrayList.size() ; ++i){}
```

loops are preferred for performance reasons to "for each" or "enhanced" style loops

```
for(Object object : objectArrayList){}
```

Does this still hold true for ART or will that change things? Just wondering.

Comment: Good question.  I haven't worked on android for years, but when I did, I wondered the same thing.  I would hope it is obsolete advice by now.

Comment: Unless you're doing very computationally intensive loops, I'd avoid worrying about it altogether and just go for the readable approach (in my opinion, that is `foreach` loops).

Comment: Agreed. Your loop finishing a millisecond sooner probably isn't worth the headache of intentionally avoiding an incredibly useful language feature.

Comment: I understand the answer to this has little practical value. I think it would only matter for really large lists. Some times I just wonder what the answer is even though it might not change how I do stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Not an Android guru :)

Seems a premature Optimization to me. Well you have a valid question though. See

```
 for(i=0; i <= objectArrayList.size() ; ++i){
       Object o = objectArrayList.get(i);
       /// do stuff
    }
```

So it traverse each time the list to get that particular element. Where as

```
for(Object object : objectArrayList){
  // do stuff
}
```

[`Uses iterator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274852/what-are-for-each-expressions-in-java-translated-to/16274893#16274893) and just a bit faster than the normal `for`. Steps over to next element.

Though I prefer  `for-each` because of readability, since all recent jvm's are super faster ;)

Comment: According to the android docs that I linked to I think they are saying for(i=0... style loops are slower on android. Again this is specific to Android. Also I am not asking because I am concerned about it slowing my apps down. The performance difference for most list sizes probably does not matter AT ALL. Its just something that I was curious about.

Comment: Also I don't think ArrayList.get(i) traverses the list.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Dalvik and ART can be really simplified to point that. Dalvik is JIT (Just-in-Time) and ART is AOT (Ahead-of-Time). This refer too the generation of executable code. So all guides that ware valid for dalvik are also valid for ART.

In your case with `ArrayList`, a better solution in term of memory allocation is the counted loop as you do not create additional instance for iterator. But in term of code maintenance the enhanced for is easier.

The guides that are currently used for Android developers ware wrote few year ago. The are updated but in case you write on device that support android K, this kind of optimization may be classified as premature.